# Permission denied on simctl using flutter

Tags: ios, flutter, xcode

I am using Flutter and I am building an app with the help of the iOS Simulator.

When I run `flutter doctor` I get the following error:

```
flutter doctor
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.7.11, on macOS 13.3.1 22E261 darwin-arm64, locale en-DE)
[✗] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices
    ✗ Unable to locate Android SDK.
      Install Android Studio from: https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html
      On first launch it will assist you in installing the Android SDK components.
      (or visit https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/macos#android-setup for detailed instructions).
      If the Android SDK has been installed to a custom location, please use
      `flutter config --android-sdk` to update to that location.

Error executing simctl: 71
xcrun: error: can't exec '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/simctl' (errno=Permission denied)


[!] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 14.3)
    ✗ Xcode requires additional components to be installed in order to run.
      Launch Xcode and install additional required components when prompted or run:
        sudo xcodebuild -runFirstLaunch
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[!] Android Studio (not installed)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.77.2)
[✓] Connected device (2 available)
[✓] HTTP Host Availability
```

I cannot build the app anymore. I never had similar issues before.

I use the following versions:

```
flutter --version
Flutter 3.7.11 • channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision f72efea43c (24 hours ago) • 2023-04-11 11:57:21 -0700
Engine • revision 1a65d409c7
Tools • Dart 2.19.6 • DevTools 2.20.1
```

```
xcodebuild -version
Xcode 14.3
Build version 14E222b
```

I already executed `sudo xcodebuild -runFirstLaunch` and it does nothing.

`flutter clean` also didn't help.

I reinstalled Xcode and flutter but it did not help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that I was not an Admin on my own Mac. I solved it by:

1. Open `System Settings`
2. Go to `Users & Groups`
3. Clicked on the "Info" button next to my account.
4. Activated `Allow this user to administer this computer`.
5. Log out and Log in again with my user.

After those steps, I was able to run `xcrun simctl list` without an error and `flutter doctor` did not show any errors anymore.